# How to use node.js/geddy with cookie

Tags: node.js, geddy

I am working on node.js's framework geddy.
Getting lots of problems in doing small things.I am not getting how cookies/session/mysql queries work in node.js.
I am even not getting decent document.I am fine with decent document link or explaination related to topics I have specified.

Answer (score 1):

Geddy provides some basic session and cookie stuff out of the box. Check out https://github.com/mde/geddy/wiki/Sessions for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Open an [issue](https://github.com/mde/geddy/issues) in Geddy's [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mde/geddy), your query will be well treated there, even by the framework creator.

If your problem is about Node.js, try to concrete what the problem is and you will get help for sure.

Answer (score -2):

They do not have any decent documentation.Thats why I had to search a lot to do such a simple task.
I did find it ,

```
npm search cookie
```

install suitable module , I have installed

```
npm install cookies
```

Then go to directoy where you have installed node modules , in my case

> /home/debugger/node_modules/

There will be directory of it , inside there is directory of examples.  (/home/debugger/node_modules/cookies/test)

Comment: Geddy provides basic session cookie support: https://github.com/mde/geddy/wiki/Sessions